# JBoss Seam Project errors

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, seam, seam2

I have a JBoss Seam project that a coworker created about a year ago. I'm taking over it now and it needs some work done. So I'm trying to setup the project in Eclipse Indigo. Here is the list of things I have installed so far:

`JBoss 4.2.2 GA`

`JBoss Seam 2.2.0 GA`

`Glassfish v2.1`

`JBoss Seam Tools Plugin for Eclipse Indigo`

For some reason I am not able to build the project to get an ear for JBoss. The errors I have are one in glassfish-builld.xml which says "Target clean does not exist in this project." And then I have errors in a bunch of generic.jsp file (I have no idea what their purpose is). The error for those is that a library for JBoss Seam called org.jboss.seam.wiki.util.WikiUtil cannot be found.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this setup and running on JBoss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also `org.jboss.seam.wiki.util.WikiUtil` is a class that is a part of... Seam example project that is added to JBoss Seam distribution in *examples/wiki* directory. So if you really need it you will be able to find it there. But honestly I don't see any reason to put any dependency to Seam examples in project. Consider just deleting / commening out the code that refers to this class becasue it is probably some quick and dirty test code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run it on Glassfish or Jboss?
Did you import an entire eclipse project or create a new one?
I would first check the referenced libraries to see if there's anything missing(Libraries under Java Build Path for Helios, not sure if that differs from Indigo).  Add a -verbose tag to the build and check out the output.